# What is the technical branch of concept at design behind the "industrial spaceship style"?

Tags: drawing, terminology, style-identification, concept-art

Look at these concept arts of spaceships [1],[2],[3].

It is clear that they "merge" heavy machinery vehicle elements and the fiction of a spaceship. I would like to know the name of this style. I tend to call this type of concept art "heavy machinery spaceships", "industrial spaceships", but I don't know for sure if the technical term for these kind of concept art are really these ones.

So, I would like to ask:

> What is the name of the concept art style of [1],[2] and [3]?

[1] https://www.artstation.com/artwork/BmOGnr

[2] https://forums.starcitizenbase.com/topic/23607-agro-mole/

[3] https://paulchadeisson.com/projects/BnL09

Comment: Not everything has a name.

Comment: I'd describe these as "sci fi spaceships/transport ships". With that being said, the actual drawing/rendering style of these examples is pretty different so could probably get more specific if you have more specific examples

Answer (score 1):

###### Photorealistic 3D renderings of conceptual spacecraft.

Not every iteration of art has some specific name. Most pieces are merely *described*.